# fastify is undefined in model

Tags: node.js, bookshelf.js, fastify

I'm trying fastify with fastify-bookshelfjs.

**contact** (model)

```
module.exports = async function (fastify) {
  console.log("4")
  fastify.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'contacts',
  })
}
```

**contact** (controller)

```
console.log("3")
const Contact = require('../models/contact')()

// Get all contact
async function getContact(req, reply) {
        const contacts = Contact.fetchAll()
        reply.code(200).send(contacts)
}
module.exports = getContact
```

**contact** (routes)

```
module.exports = async function (fastify) {
  console.log("2")
  const contact = require('../controller/contact')

  fastify.get('/', contact.getContact)
}
```

When the server start I get this output

```
2
3
4
(node:10939) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'bookshelf' of undefined
1
server listening on 3000
```

Why fastify in contact(model) is undefined and how can fix ?

Comment: Could you add how you register these `module.exports`? Because I think your problem is caused by a wrong set of encapsulation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `controller`, when you import the model, you need to put `fastify` as argument.

Also, you have to import the `fastify` module.

Your contact (controller) should be

```
const fastify = require('fastify') // import the fastify module here
console.log("3")
const Contact = require('../models/contact')(fastify)

// Get all contact
async function getContact(req, reply) {
        const contacts = Contact.fetchAll()
        reply.code(200).send(contacts)
}
module.exports = getContact
```